# How do I determine the users notification alert style?

Tags: macos, cocoa

In the System Preferences Notifications settings the user can select None, Banners or Alerts for each app. How can I determine the users chosen setting for my app? I've been searching on-line and in the docs without any success so far.

I've looked at [How to check Notification alert style for our app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046135/how-to-check-notification-alert-style-for-our-app) but that's for ios and is more about setting the alert style. I don't want to change the alert style - I just want to know what the user has set it to.

Comment: What is the purpose? Just implement the handling for all types passed in the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` method

Comment: If the user has set their notification alert style to None I want to show a dialog instead.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` seems to only be relevant to whether apps launched by remote notifications display a badge or not. My question is about the chosen alert style (None, Banner or Alert) for our app.